# DataGridView Results

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to build a search function in VB.net. My intention is to take the string input chop it up and return results depending on those sub-strings. The problem is I am getting multiple copies of the same thing returned. hence why I added the code below. For example if I search "wifi not working" I will get three copies of the same thing back, I only want one copy of the same result but I want to keep the flexibility of searching sub-strings. Please assist.

```
 For Each rowy As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                            If element(0).ToString = rowy.Cells(0).Value.ToString Then
                            Else
                                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(element(0).ToString)
                            End If
```

### Next

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim searchQuery As String
    Dim table = New DataTable
    Dim words() As String

    'Store String, segregate string into list
    Private Sub SearchBttn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchBttn.Click
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        searchQuery = SearchBox.Text
        words = searchQuery.Split(TryCast(Nothing, String()), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        SearchResults(words)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        table.Columns.Add("result")
        table.Rows.Add("Unlock LAN account")
        table.Rows.Add("Wifi Not Working")
        table.Rows.Add("Account Error - 1230")

    End Sub


    Private Sub SearchResults(value As Array)
        For Each element As DataRow In table.Rows
            For i As Integer = 0 To value.Length - 1
                Dim upperElem As String = element(0).ToString.ToUpper
                Dim upperVal As String = value(i).ToString.ToUpper
                If (upperElem.Contains(upperVal)) Then
                    If DataGridView1.RowCount = 0 Then
                        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(element(0).ToString)
                    Else
                        For Each rowy As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                            If element(0).ToString = rowy.Cells(0).Value.ToString Then
                            Else
                                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(element(0).ToString)
                            End If
                        Next

                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Array.Clear(words, 0, words.Length)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Looks like because you are looping through each table row you are doing the same calculation. If you added another row on load, do you get four returns?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `BindingSource`, set its `DataSource` to the `DataTable` and bind it to `DataGridView.DataSource`. This makes things alot easier.

Additionally you can avoid alot of code in your `SearchResults` method by using Linq.

In advance using `ToUpper` on strings is deprecated and should be replaced by either setting `Option Comapre Text` or using case invariant comparisons like `"a".Equals("A",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Here is my reworked code which should give you a good start:

```
Option Comapre Text
... 

Dim bs As New BindingSource
...

'Store String, segregate string into list
Private Sub SearchBttn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click      
    searchQuery = SearchBox.Text
    words = searchQuery.Split(TryCast(Nothing, String()), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    SearchResults(words)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    table.Columns.Add("result")
    table.Rows.Add("Unlock LAN account")
    table.Rows.Add("Wifi Not Working")
    table.Rows.Add("Account Error - 1230")
    bs.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs     'Remove this line if the grid should be empty first 
End Sub

Private Sub SearchResults(ParamArray values As String())
    Dim filteredRows = table.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Where(Function(r) values.Any(Function(s) r(0).ToString.Contains(s))) 'Find any row which contains any of the given filter words
    If(filteredRows.Any)
        bs.DataSource = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable 'Bind grid to found rows
    Else
        bs.DataSource = table 'Reset grid to show all rows. Remove this if grid should be empty if nothing is found
    End If
    bs.ResetBindings(False)
End Sub
```

**Important hint**: This and your code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection since the input string is used unfiltered. You should remove or escape any malicious strings from the search string before processing the filtering (assuming the current filling of the DataTable is just for debugging and you will use SQL later on).